# Nestjs docker run Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, deployment, nestjs

I built nest app and apply docker for deploy to server
Nest app work as well in local dev environment
I wrote `Dockerfile` by refer docker tutorial video/article

Dockerfile code below :

```
# Dockerfile
From node:16
# Specify app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Paste source
COPY . .

# Build
RUN npm run build

# Set port
EXPOSE 3000

# Run app
CMD [ "node", "dist/main"]
# CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod"] # for testing
```

I guess scripts has not changed but write it down in case you don't know.

```
# package.json (scripts)
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
```

I understand docker build process the above comments in Dockerfile and write like that
And run `docker build ./ -t <name>`, `docker run <name>`
But error occurred docker build and **run** that `Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/main'`

Error message below:

```
% docker run <name>
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

My question/curious is

1. Why `WORKDIR` command has not create `/usr/src/app` directory
2. Why `RUN npm run build` has not create bundled file(main.js) in dist directory (I confirmed run `npm run build` command directly in dev environment, that create `main.js` in dist directory)

And I tried

1. Change WORKDIR `<path>` (access, permissions ..)
2. Remove `node_module`, `package-lock.json` and `npm install` (re-install dependencies)
3. Comment out `RUN npm run build`, `CMD ["node", "dist/main"]` and add command `CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
4. And parameter changes ..

Please advice to me
thanks

Comment: When you run `nest build` locally, do you get a `dist` directory with a `main.js` file?

Comment: Yes when build started, the `dist` directory is deleted and re-created with the `main.js` file when the app build is complete.

Comment: My guess then would be that the `dist` is created differently in the two environments for some reason. You can do `docker run -it <name> sh` and use `ls` and `cd` to navigate and read the directory contents inside the created container

Comment: I didn't know how to debug it at docker build time. Thank you for letting me know. and i debugging it, conclusion is bundled file has positioned at `dist/src`(one more step). I didn't know how it created in `dist/src` but  i change my `dockerfile` settings then app works thanks!

Comment: And can I one more question? `/usr/src/app` directory is not found when actually accessing the path after exit the command. When docker shuts down, does that directory disappear? that directory only exist at working time?

Comment: When you `sh` into it, you should already be at `usr/src/app`. You could do `cd ../../..` to verify that there is a `usr` directory